# Upload file to j2ee spring, file is null

Tags: javascript, spring, jakarta-ee, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a file to my J2eE spring backend. But if I set file required then it does not recognize, so therefor i conclude that it must be the way I try to send it from the front end.
HTML definition:

```
 <form id="filesUploadForm" action="spring/uploadFile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input class="std" id="file" type="file" name="choose">
 </form>
```

Javascript: (Which is triggered from another button)

```
function uploadFile() {
var url = 'spring/uploadFile';

var formData = $('#filesUploadForm').serialize();
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', url, true);
xhr.onload = function() {
    console.log('upload complete');
};
xhr.send(formData);
```

}

If it is relevant: here is the Java code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void uploadFile(@RequestParam(value = "file", required = false) MultipartFile multipartFile) {
    String fileName = multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();
    System.out.println(fileName);
}
```

Comment: What's your controller request mapping, is it 'spring'? Also - as you're using jQuery - don't use XMLHttpRequest(), you can just do `$.post('url', fileBlob);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to change the parameter name in your Java code:

```
@RequestParam(value = "choose", required = false)
```